# Is there any way to handling an Exception for Ruby's SyntaxError "both arg and actual block given"?

Tags: ruby

I want to write a method passing a block, but if a proc and an actual block are given at the same time,  it will take only the first one.

I have tried to raise an Exception for SyntaxError, but it keeps prompting an error. This is one of the things that I was trying.

```
def my_map(&proc)
    raise SyntaxError, "using first block given"
  rescue
    arr = []
    proc = proc.call(i) || yield(i)
    self.my_each do |i|
      arr << proc
    end
    arr
  end
```

I also tried to add a condition for the raise keyword.

Of course, code works if only one block is given.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question if `my_map` is called as `my_map(&-> {'hello'}) {'goodbye'})` then a `SyntaxError` will already be raised (outside of the method body). If `my_map` is called as `my_map {'hello'}` then `proc` is that block so `proc.call` and `yield` are identical in functionality. So in essence this already does what you want with too much additional complexity because calling any method with 2 blocks is not legal syntax

Comment: You would need to do the rescue outside the method - it's the _call_ to the method that's erroring, not the _body_ of the method. Also, `proc = proc.call(i) || yield(i)` looks wrong - don't you just want to test for the existence of `proc`, rather than call it here? And you can call `block_given?` to see if a block was passed.

Comment: If you want to pass a proc `p` as an argument and also provide a block to be acted up by `yield`, just write `def my_map(p)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a method passing a block, but if a proc and an actual block are given at the same time, it will take only the first one.

```rb
def f(*args)
  if args.length == 1
    args.first.call
  else
    yield
  end
end

puts 'test 1'
f(->() { puts 'a' }) { puts 'b' }

puts 'test 2'
f { puts 'b' }
```

Output

```
test 1
a
test 2
b
```

Comment: While functional this is hideous and invokes the need to ask why one would do this.Also should likely raise under multiple currently unhandled conditions.

Comment: I checked. It has two blocks and picks the first one, but I was trying to take a proc and an actual block. Thank, anyway! I'm not sure if this is even possible.